# Mongoose.findOne returns same document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get the mongodb document by its id using express as a backend. The findOne & populate query returns the same document every time I make request to route.I want to return a patients data by Id.Can anybody please help me with this. I am new to JavaScript.

```
// @ route  GET api/profile/patient/:patientId
// @ desc   Get patient by patientId
// @ access Private

router.get('/:patient_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const patient_profile = await Patient.findOne({

        patient: req.params._id

      }).populate('patient');
      //console.log(patient);
      console.log(patient_profile);
      if (!patient_profile) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Patient not found' });

      res.json(patient_profile);    
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      if (err.kind == 'ObjectId') {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Profile not found' });
      }
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: `req.params.patient_id`?

Comment: Hi Ayush.. the function now returns null.. Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To access the ID on the request parameter use code below...

```
req.params.patient_id
```

your mistake was

```
req.params._id
```

Comment: Hi James..Still the function returns same document.

Comment: Try using findById(req.params.patient_id, function(err, data){// do stuff here}) instead of 'findOne'. good luck!

Comment: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ patient: '5d0ba1b6f011b1538c0fb0bc' }" at path "_id" for model "patient" Hi james getting this output on console

Comment: remove '.populate('patient')'... the populate function is only used to get referenced document.

Comment: Hi james..Also can you help me with query to find record by phonenumber..I have phonumber field in my databse. Request your help as I new to programming.

Comment: Hi James.. Thanks a lot will surely go through it!